# new WinForms.PrintDialog() does nothing on Windows 7 x64

Tags: wpf, printing

Printing works on Win7 x86, Windows XP.
On Windows 7 x64, this code does nothing. Nor does it throw any excpetion. 
I have no ideas, googleing does not help. 
Maybe someone has experience with this issue?
Thanks.

```
System.Drawing.Font printFont = new System.Drawing.Font("Courier New", 10);
                DataTablePrintDocument printDoc = new DataTablePrintDocument(this, printFont);

                WinForms.PrintDialog dlg = new WinForms.PrintDialog();

                WinForms.DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restoring your system fonts to original, this fixed the issue for me a while ago.
 ;)

As it works in x86 and xp it is no coding error.

Comment: Hi, what you mean by restoring font?

Comment: This will help you to find the restore button: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/how-to-restore-windows-7-default-fonts/73a8eb3e-3189-4514-b87c-18fcdca4fe26

Comment: Thanks, but changeing fonts on Windows is not solution. I am building application that must work on any win7 x64 computer.

Comment: Could you try another font, just to test if it makes any difference? Does restoring your font helps?

Comment: dlg.UseEXDialog = true; fixed problem!